# Указатель на указатель - что это?

Tags: указатели, синтаксис, c++

Часто встречаю вот такую конструкцию:

```
int ** p;
```

Я так понимаю, что это указатель на указатель. Зачем такая двойственность нужна и где применяется?

Comment: [баян же][1]


  [1]: http://cppstudio.com/post/9555/

Comment: @DreamChild извиняюсь, не узрел, сейчас почитаю.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Указатель в C — не семантика, а механизм. Он сам по себе не несёт смысла, но может *использоваться* для выражения того или иного смысла. То же относится и к двойному указателю: он может использоваться для разных вещей. Вот несколько примеров.

1. В C параметры передаются по значению, то есть из коробки нету передачи параметров «по ссылке» (они же `&`-параметры C++, они же `ref`-/`out`-параметры C#). Для того, чтобы объявить такой параметр, пользуются указателем на фактический параметр (то есть, передают в функцию адрес параметра). Если тип самого параметра — указатель, получается двойной указатель. Пример:

   ```
   void split_half(char* input, char** first_half, char** second_half)
   {
       var len = strlen(input);
       var halflen = len / 2;
       *first_half = malloc(halflen + 1);
       strncpy(*first_half, input, halflen);
       (*firsthalf)[halflen] = 0;
       *second_half = strdup(&input[halflen]);
   }
   ```
2. В C указатель может обозначать массив. Если тип элемента массива — указатель, получается двойной указатель. Классический пример:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char** argv) { ... }
   ```
3. Двойной указатель можно использовать для массива массивов. Например, квадратная матрица:

   ```
   struct matrix
   {
       int** data;
       int width;
       int height;
   }

   void init_matrix(int width, int height, struct matrix* matrix)
   {
       matrix->width = width;
       matrix->height = height;
       matrix->data = malloc(height * sizeof(int*));
       for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
           matrix->data[y] = malloc(width * sizeof(int));
   }
   ```

---

В C++ обычно ручное управление памятью не приветствуется, поэтому там кратные указатели встречаются куда реже.

Answer (score 3):

Ни в языке С++, ни в языке С, нет такого понятия, как "указатель на указатель" в виде *самостоятельной* сущности с какими-то новыми качественными свойствами. Поэтому в строгом смысле слова, вопрос о том "зачем нужен указатель на указатель" не имеет никакого смысла.

В языках С и С++ есть такое понятие, как *указатель*. Просто *указатель*. Т.е. если у вас есть некий тип `T`, то вы можете объявить *указатель* `p` на этот тип

```
T *p;
```

и заставить этот указатель указывать на объект `t` типа `T`

```
T t;
p = &t;
```

После этого выражения `t` и `*p` будут обозначать один и тот же объект. Т.е. если вы, например, поменяете значение объекта `*p`, то тем самым вы поменяете и объект `t` (и наоборот). Вы можете также завести еще сколько угодно указателей на один и от же объект.

Это - элементарные основы идеи *указателя*.

Ну так а далее можно просто заметить, что тип `T` сам по себе может быть указательным типом. Но это совершенно ничего не меняет. Нет ничего принципиально разного между ситуацией, когда `T` - это `int`, и ситуацией, когда `T` - это `double *`. Все вышесказанное относится к обоим случаям в одинаковой мере.

Вот, собственно и все. Т.е. нет никакого смысла вводить в рассмотрение такую сущность, как "указатель на указатель", и устраивать вокруг нее какие-то обсуждения. Все, что нам нужно - это обычный указатель, который может просто-напросто указывать и на другой указатель. Но эти два уровня указательности (три, четыре, пять уровней...) совершенно отдельны, ничего о друг друге не знают и знать не хотят.

И рассматривать такие указатели надо как обычные указатели. То же самое в полной мере справедливо и об "указателях на указатели на указатели", "указателях на указатели на указатели на указатели" и т.д. до бесконечности.

Answer (score 2):

Когда-то объяснял это на примере холодильника.

```
int **fridge; // Холодильник с полочками на которых еда
*fridge; // Полочка в холодильнике
**fridge; // Колбаса
```

Comment: Я так понял, что эта конструкция нужна для создания динамического массива, и чтоб не копировать все данные заново, копируются только их указатели-индексы с расширением индекса и с последующим его заполнением.

Comment: Ну да, вы правы в целом. Про realloc, кстати, недавно очень годная статья была http://habrahabr.ru/company/abbyy/blog/238739/

Comment: @iksuy я си-шного распределения памяти боюсь как огня. )

Answer (score 0):

Эта конструкция нужна для создания динамического массива, и чтоб не копировать все данные заново, копируются только их указатели-индексы с расширением индекса и с последующим его заполнением.

Comment: Часто это действительно так, но совершенно не обязательно. 

Указатель на указатель также часто используют в качестве аргумента функции, которая "возвращает больше одного результата".

  
В качестве примера можете посмотреть `man 3 getline`, `man 3 strtok_r`, `man 3 strtol`...

Comment: @avp, согласен, дополнить ответ развернутым объяснением, что аргументы функции после ее завершения остаются неизменными (даже если внутри их можно менять), и поэтому туда передают указатель на указатель, когда надо менять указатель, и получится полноценный емкий ответ :)

Comment: @smallFish, так своим комменарием Вы уже и расставили все "точки над и".

Могу только еще раз отослать автора к чтению **Example** в [man 3 strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol).

Comment: @avp @smallFish это четко видно по примеру, который показал @DreamChild, там есть такая функция с таким аргументом.

Answer (score 0):

Например, указатель на начало динамического массива динамических массивов. Или на элемент динамического массива динамических массивов. Или адрес, по которому лежит другой указатель, чтоб функция могла поменять значение этого другого указателя.