# Указатель на указатель на указатель

Tags: c++, c

Интересно кто нибудь на практике сталкивался  с конструкциями указатель на указатель на указатель и т.д. именно там где это необходимо было ?
P.S интересует конструкция вида *** p и т.д. а не **p

Comment: Сталкивался. Это весь вопрос?

Comment: Хотелось  бы посмотреть код где такое актуально если только не многомерные массивы

Comment: при определенном подходе, связанный список можно считать "указателем на указатель на указатель на .... указатель".

Comment: В тему: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/378325/%d0%a3%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be?rq=1

Comment: не много не в тему там вопрос о конструкции типа int **p это довольно обыденая конструкции и её применение логично,  а вопрос про int ***p

Comment: Как еще один пример, такая конструкция встречается в моделировании 3D объектов. Как раз трехмерная структура {x,y,z} дает тройной указатель.

Comment: Думаю, знакомы с `main(int ac, char *av[])`? Представьте функцию, которая делает (в динамической памяти (например, в куче)) новый `av[]`. Так вот, ее аргументом как раз и будет `***p`, т.е. адрес переменной типа `char **` в которую она поместит адрес первого элемента вектора av[]

Comment: Господа, модераторы(?)! На самом деле в вопросе-ответах по ссылке интересующий ТС `***p` не рассматривается (или хорошо замаскирован).

Comment: @avp, в принятом ответе в первом предложении.

Comment: @Nofate, естественно, я имел в виду не ответ **здесь**, а ответы в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/378325/ (на который идет ссылка, поскольку **этот вопрос отмечен как дубликат**) Так вот там, я ничего о `***p` не увидел.

Comment: @avp, так и я про него. Там же VladD пишет про общую концепцию. И если *"Двойной указатель можно использовать для массива массивов"*, очевидно, что тройной можно использовать для массива двумерных массивов (массивов массивов).

Comment: @Nofate, я безусловно, не сомневаюсь в существовании людей, которые наблюдая за каплей воды могут сделать вывод о существовании океанов, но вряд ли можно считать, что ответ VladD (и остальные там) четко отвечают на конкретный вопрос -- `Интересно кто нибудь на практике сталкивался с конструкциями указатель на указатель на указатель и т.д. именно там где это необходимо было ?` (или это опять пресловутый "опросник", который должен быть нещадно искоренен?)

Comment: @avp "код где такое актуально если только не многомерные массивы"! Массивы это понятно - многомерные массивы так и созданы быть указателем на указатель и т.д. в зависимости от вложенности  там  нельзя по другому, я хотел увидеть практическое применение использование такой конструкции  в местах где можно написать по другому

Comment: Так вопрос ведь никто не удаляет. Снизу - конкретный случай, в той ветке - общий. Зада решена, идем дальше разгребать неотвеченное )

Comment: @Nofate, а я почему-то считал, что дубликаты вы тоже удаляете... (впрочем, при складывающейся обстановке, это уже не очень важно)

Comment: Нет, дубликаты так и остаются лежать, повышая релевантность ответа, на который они ссылаются.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Задача: создать массив строк, вернуть его размер, в случае ошибки: -1.

Сигнатура метода:

```
ssize_t make_string_array(char ***ptr)
```

`make_string_array()`, к примеру, читает строки из файла, но не суть. Массив строк - двойной указатель, а тройной нужен, что бы вернуть адрес этого безобразия.

Вызов такой:

```
char **ptr;
ssize_t count;
count = make_string_array(&ptr);
if (count == -1) {
  perror("make_string_array()");
  exit(1)
}
```

Перебрать:

```
for (ssize_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  printf("str[%d]=%s\n", i, ptr[i]);
}
```

Ну и вместо строк может быть, к примеру, массив указателей на объекты ну или ещё что-то.

По сути вопроса: да, сталкивался. да, было оправдано (как минимум было далеко не худшим решением).