# Разница между одиночным и двойным указателем для хранения данных матрицы

Tags: c++

Создаю собственный класс Matrix и возник вопрос в каком виде хранить данные. Например:

```
T* data = nullptr; //одиночный указатель
T** data = nullptr; // двойной
```

Как преимущества и недостатки у каждого вида хранения данных? Кроме того, что мы используем большее число аллокаций у двойного указателя

Comment: Здесь вы найдете ответ на свой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/378325/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE

Comment: `T*` - это указатель на переменную типа `T`, либо указатель на массив элементов типа `T`. `T**` - это указатель на указатель на переменную типа `T`, либо указатель на массив указателей на переменные типа `T`, либо указатель на массив указателей на массивы элементов типа `T`.

Comment: Данные не хранятся в указателях.

Comment: Разница в аллокации памяти для двумерного массива. В первом случае выделяется память одним куском и для доступа к элементам используется арифметика указателей. Во втором случае - выделяется сколько-то отдельных кусков памяти под каждую строчку в массиве. В первом случае работа с массивом (адресация) происходит быстрее (в общем случае). При небольших размерах массивов, небольшом количестве операций и современных оптимизаторах - в реальности разницу можно не увидеть.